# Стрелки влево и вправо в javascript (для фотогалереи)

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция:

```
   function keyPressHandler(e) {
        if (!isOpen) return;

        e = e || window.event;
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : (e.which ? e.which : e.charCode),
            fnList = {
                110 : G.next,       // n key
                98  : G.prev,       // b key
                102 : G.zoomNormal, // f key
                43  : G.zoomIn,     // +
                45  : G.zoomOut,    // -
                27  : G.close       // Esc key
            };

        fnList[code] && fnList[code]();
    }
```

Непонятно, как делать стрелки влево и вправо для них? В списке не нашел номер стрелки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вправо - 39, Влево - 37, вверх - 38, вниз - 40.
Проверить можно с помощью такой нехитрой штуки:

```js
"use strict";

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  document.querySelector("p > span").innerHTML = event.keyCode;
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Код нажатой клавиши: <span>xx</span>.</p>
```